# Drawing surfaces with BSurface, get many wrinkles and stripy texture

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am creating a surface using BSurface plugin (great plugin!!), my surface is very large (10 km2) and the result is a very "stripy" looking surface. [image: Stripy texture on surface] [image: Edit mode, same shot] I have applied auto smooth, smooth shading, subdivision surface modifier, decimate surface, laplacian smooth modifier, corrective smooth and smooth modifiers and still have a unnatural stripy surface.

I suspect this stripy texture is because the surface is drawn between two curves and is interpolated along a straight line. [image: Straight (near vertical) line between two GP lines] However, I still get a stripy look when i use many lines to interpolate my surface (see image of surface drawn with 10 lines) [image: BSurface drawn with 10 GP lines]. Has anyone figured a way around this? For example, can you draw a surface, then changes its shape by drawing a 3rd grease pencil line? What is the best way to remove these wrinkles?

Comment: Your curve resolution is too dense resulting in non-uniform mesh density that leads to artifacts. Reduce the density of the mesh in the tighter direction by reducing the resolution of the curve

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for the comment, unfortunately I do not want to loose too much resolution on some of the lines. I just tried this approach and then smoothed and decimated the surface, the wrinkles are gone, but the resolution is too low on the original line.

Comment: If you don't want to loose resolution in one direction then increase it in the other so they are more uniform. Uneven density across directions causes wrinkles to appear.

Comment: Maybe I am unclear on what you mean, but increasing the resolution until it is equal in all directions still gives the wrinkle pattern, then when i change the shape of the surface the wrinkle pattern gets worse.  I think the best work around is to reduce the resolution, decimate, then snap the surface back to the original line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an align verts with grease pencil tool. You should be able to use this to line your vertices up, and get rid of that weird affect. You may have to download an addon though...

Comment: Looks like this in combination with reducing resolution and decimating may be the best solution. Restoring the resolution of the original line can be done after these steps by snapping the surface back to the line where it has been simplified.